# How to have parent object fill list while child object consumes list

Tags: c#, task, task-parallel-library

I'm trying to implement a model where a parent object spins up a new child object with a List<> property.  The parent will be adding items to the List<> while the child is processing items in the List<>.  This would be asynchronous with the parent adding items at different times while the children just churn through the items in the List<> and then sit idle whenever the List<> has been exhausted.  The parent doesn't need to wait for the child method to complete, the parent just invokes the child method and then waits for the next info to come in for updating the List<> of a child.

Ideally, each child would inform the parent (callback) when it has sat idle too long so the parent could kill that child.

For both methods to be processing at the same time, I recognize each would have to be on a separate thread.  Maybe someone has some sample code they could share to guide me in the right direction.  I've just stumbled upon the new (to me) System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel Library and am looking into it.

I know I could implement this as two separate processes each operating on the same queue (a DB table or something similar), but I'd rather not go that route unless it just can't be done using C# and separate threads.

**UPDATE**: From Rahul's answer, I found this article which has been very helpful with several examples:  [BlockingCollection Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/blockingcollection-overview)

**UPDATE**: This article on the variances of Task has also been helpful with regard to understanding thread management: [A Tour of Task](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/04/a-tour-of-task-part-0-overview.html)

Comment: Search "Producer Consumer Pattern"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are talking about *Producer Consumer pattern* and in that case you can use [`BlockingCollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx#Examples) which is a implementation of such. Quoting from linked doc page

> `BlockingCollection<T>` is a thread-safe collection class that
>   provides the following:
>
> An implementation of the producer/consumer pattern;
>   BlockingCollection is a wrapper for the
>   IProducerConsumerCollection interface.